# How to make QTabWidget transparent?

Tags: c++, qt

Actually I am trying to make the QTabWidget's background to transparent but I could not do that even i tried background-color: transparent but still it does not work. do you have any idea?

My Qt version:5.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QSS style to control the background style of QTabWidget.

```
QTabWidget::pane {
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that (in my testing on Ubuntu), if you don't include the `border: 0` line, the background won't be transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the "documentMode" property on the QTabWidget.

You can achieve this by adding the following code:

```c
tabWidget::setDocumentMode(true) // C/C++
```

```py
tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True) # Python
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the flowing stylesheet to create a transparent background QTabWidget

```
QWidget{background:transparent} QTabWidget::pane{border: 1px;border-color:red;background-color: transparent;} 
QTabBar::tab {background-color: transparent;color: #ccc;width: 280px;height:48px;font-size:24px} 
QTabBar::tab:hover{background-color:#ddd; color: white;}     
QTabBar::tab:selected{background-color: #363535; color: #008BEA;}
```

I think QWidget{background:transparent} is essential.